# How to delete pending pods in kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, mariadb, containers

I have two pending pods which I cannot delete by any means. Could you help?
OS: Cent OS 7.8
Docker: 1.13.1
kubenetes: "v1.20.1"

```
[root@master-node ~]# k get pods --all-namespaces    (note: k = kubectl alias)
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
**default                happy-panda-mariadb-master-0                 0/1     Pending**   0          11m
**default                happy-panda-mariadb-slave-0                  0/1     Pending**   0          49m
default                whoami                                       1/1     Running   0          5h13m


[root@master-node ~]# k describe pod/happy-panda-mariadb-master-0
Name:           happy-panda-mariadb-master-0
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=mariadb
                chart=mariadb-7.3.14
                component=master
                controller-revision-hash=happy-panda-mariadb-master-7b55b457c9
                release=happy-panda
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=happy-panda-mariadb-master-0

IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/happy-panda-mariadb-master
Containers:
  mariadb:
    Image:      docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3.22-debian-10-r27
    Port:       3306/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Liveness:   exec [sh -c password_aux="${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD:-}"
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-happy-panda-mariadb-master-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      happy-panda-mariadb-master
    Optional:  false
  default-token-wpvgf:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-wpvgf
    Optional:    false

Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  15m   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  15m   default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

[root@master-node ~]# k get events
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON             OBJECT                                                    MESSAGE
105s        Normal    FailedBinding      persistentvolumeclaim/data-happy-panda-mariadb-master-0   no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
105s        Normal    FailedBinding      persistentvolumeclaim/data-happy-panda-mariadb-slave-0    no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
65m         Warning   FailedScheduling   pod/happy-panda-mariadb-master-0                          0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
```

I already tried delete by various ways but nothing worked (I also tried to delete from the dashboard)

```
**kubectl delete pod happy-panda-mariadb-master-0 --namespace="default"
k delete deployment mysql-1608901361
k delete pod/happy-panda-mariadb-master-0 -n default --grace-period 0 --force**
```

Could you advise me on this?

Answer (score 1):

kubectl delete rc replica set names

Or You forgot to specify storageClassName: manual in PersistentVolumeClaim.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the statefulset which controls the pods instead of deleting the pods directly. The reason pods are not getting deleted is because statefulset controller is recreating them after you delete it.

```
kubectl delete statefulset happy-panda-mariadb-master
```

Comment: wow, Arghya, thank you very much, it really worked out. Really appreciate your advise!